# separate comma delimited cells in the specified column to new rows with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bioinformatics

I have a table with comma delimited columns and I want to separate the comma delimited values in my specified column to new rows. For example, the given table is

Name Start Name2

A 1,2 X,a

B 5 Y,b

C 6,7,8 Z,c

And I need to separate the comma delimited values in column 2 to get the table below

Name Start Name2

A 1 X,a

A 2 X,a

B 5 Y,b

C 6 Z,c

C 7 Z,c

C 8 Z,c

I am wondering if there is any solution with shell script, so that I can create a workflow pipe. Note: the original table may contain more than 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bash solution produces your desired output

```
{
     read header; echo "$header"
     while read name start rest; do
         for elem in $(tr , " " <<< "$start"); do
             echo "$name $elem $rest"
         done
     done
} << END
Name Start Name2
A 1,2 X,a
B 5 Y,b
C 6,7,8 Z,c
END
```

less verbose

```
awk 'NR==1 {print; next} {split($2,a,/,/); for (i in a) {$2=a[i]; print}}'
```

Comment: I have tested this script, perfect!!

Comment: Thanks for the update. The awk command runs much much faster than you previous scripts (<1 second for a 25000 line file, but the other script took several minutes!!!). BTW, can I change the output of your awk command to tab delimited table?

Comment: I have found out how to define the output delimiter. But I don't understand why the default output delimiter here is a space. In my impression, the default output of awk should be tab delimited.

Comment: @Runner, I don't know where you got that idea: the default value of `OFS` is space. Check the awk man page.